# Id для элемента listview

Tags: list, android, listview, java

Здравствуйте. Есть активность, унаследованная от ListView.
Как можно задать для каждого элемента свой уникальный идентификатор, который я напишу самостоятельно?

Код заполения следующий:

```
public class UrCatalog extends ListActivity {

    ArrayList<item> items = new ArrayList<item>();

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        items.add(new SectionItem("Регистрация юридических лиц и индивидуальных предпринимателей"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Регистрация ООО"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Регистрация ЗАО, АО, ОАО"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Регистрация НКО"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Регистрация ИП"));
```

,где `SectionItem` является "разделом" в списке.
id нужен для последующего подключения к БД, где каждому элементу соответствует строка таблицы (элемент с id = 1, соответствующая строка таблицы с id = 1). `Position` не могу использовать, т.к. `Position` считает элементы с 0 и берет в расчет элементы `SectionItem`, которые мне не важны.

Answer (score 2):

Переопределите `getItemId` у адаптера `ListView` и возвращайте нужное значение.

Comment: можно поподробней как это сделать на примере моего кода?

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял суть вопроса, то имеется некий класс, хранящий инфу для работы с базой ( `_id` и остальные данные  ) 
На его основе строится список `ListView` и нужно знать `_id` выбранного элемента для работы с базой.
Все это позволяет сделать обычный адаптер, никто не мешает получать выбранный объект  и его  `_id`. 
Если не правильно понял, уточни вопрос.